# Cloudwatch rule to match ssm hierarchy

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, ssm

I'd like to create a cloudwatch rule to trigger an action whenever a SSM parameter in a given hiearchy is updated (in my example anything in the `/config` hierarchy)

If I put a rule matching the whole name of the parameter the action gets triggered correctly.

I tried the following thus far:

```
    {
  "source": [
    "aws.ssm"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Parameter Store Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "name": [
      "/config/",
      "/config/*",
      "/config/%"
    ],
    "operation": [
      "Update"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve such behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but you can leave off the "name" array entirely. You will then get notifications for all parameters, and then filter from the message receive side.